# Paralelizing an Rscript using a job array in Slurm

Tags: r, shell, slurm

I want to run an Rscript.R using an array job in Slurm, with 1-10 tasks, whereby the task id from the job will be directed to the Rscript, to write a file named "'task id'.out", containing 'task id' in its body. However, this has proven to be more challenging than I anticipated haha I am trying the following:

~/bash_test.sh looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash -l
#SBATCH --time=00:01:00
#SBATCH --array=1-10
conda activate R
cd ~/test 
R CMD BATCH --no-save --no-restore ~/Rscript_test.R $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID
```

~/Rscript_test.R looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
taskid = commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)
# taskid <- Sys.getenv('SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID')
taskid <- as.data.frame(taskid)
# print task number
print(paste0("the number processed was... ", taskid))
write.table(taskid, paste0("~/test/",taskid,".out"),quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
```

After I submit my job (`sbatch bash_test.sh`), it looks like R is not really seeing `SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID`. The script is generating 10 files (1, 2, ..., 10 - just numbers - probably corresponding to the task ids), but it's not writing the files with the extension ".out": the script wrote an empty "integer(0).out" file.

What I wanted, was to populate the folder `~/test/` with 10 files, 1.out, 2.out, ..., 10.out, and each file has to contain the task id inside (simply the number 1, 2, ..., or 10, respectively).

P.S.: Note that I tried playing with `Sys.getenv()` too, but I don't think I was able to set that up properly. That option generates 10 files, and one 1.out file, containing number 10.

P.S.2: This is slurm 19.05.5. I am running R wihthin a conda environment.

Comment: I don't think you want `taskid <- as.data.frame(taskid)`. Putting it in a data.frame will break using it in `paste()`. Are the files being written to `~/test` or are they going to your current working directory? What version of slurm are you running (`sbatch --version`). Are you getting a `slurm-*.out` file for the master job ID?

Comment: Thanks, @MrFlick. The files are going straight into `~/test` because in my bash script it's got a `cd ~/test` before running `R CMD BATCH [...]`. I accidentally had removed from my post here, but I've edited this now.

As for slurm version, it's `19.05.5`. I'll edit my post too. 

Re. stdout files, I am getting them in the `~/test` folder, named after the task ids (1, 2, ..., 10). The print line results in:


`[1] "the number processed was... integer(0)"`

Comment: P.S.: I initially tried `taskid <- as.integer(taskid)`, which returned `task_id` as `integer(0)`, so that's why I tried changing it to a data.frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should avoid using "R CMD BATCH". It doesn't handle arguments the way most functions do. "Rscript" has been the recommended option for a while now. By calling "R CMD BATCH" you are basically ignoring the "#!/usr/bin/env Rscript" part of your script.

So change your script file to

```
#!/bin/bash -l
#SBATCH --time=00:01:00
#SBATCH --array=1-10
conda activate R
cd ~/test 
Rscript ~/Rscript_test.R $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID
```

And then becareful in your script that you aren't using the same variable as both a string a data.frame. You can't easily paste a data.frame into a file path for example. So

```
taskid <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)
# taskid <- Sys.getenv('SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID')  # This should also work

print(paste0("the number processed was... ", taskid))

outdata <- as.data.frame(taskid)
outfile <- paste0("~/test/", taskid, ".out")

write.table(outdata, outfile, quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
```

The extra files with just the array number were created because the usage of R CMD BATCH is

```
R CMD BATCH [options] infile [outfile]
```

So the `$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID` value you were passing at the command line was treated as the outfile name. Instead that value needed to be passed as options. But again, it's better to use Rscript which has more standard argument conventions.

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly! And thank you for the information re. `Rscript` vs `R CMD BATCH`

Comment: P.S.: I think you forgot to include `#!/usr/bin/env Rscript` in the beggining of the Rscript.R above.

Comment: @RodrigoDuarte If you are calling `Rscript` directly, that line is not necessary at all. That's only relevant if you try to execute the script file directly.

Comment: Ohhhh, I see. Sorry - still learning! Thanks again!

Comment: Can I ask you something else, please? I am finding that my `taskid` variable can't be included in a formula to subset a `data.frame`. I wanted to `single_value_from_df <- as.character(df[taskid,4])`, to extract the row corresponding to `taskid` from column 4 of `df`. However, I am getting the error:

`Error in `[.data.table`(base, taskid, 4) :
  When i is a data.table (or character vector), the columns to join by must be specified using 'on=' argument (see ?data.table), by keying x (i.e. sorted, and, mar$
Calls: source -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> [ -> [.data.table
Execution halted`

Comment: ... while I know that that sub-setting works absolutely fine in that case if I specify just a random number (within the number of rows in my table), instead of `taskid`.

Comment: Sorry - responding myself. I just had to force `taskid` as an integer:
`single_value_from_df <- as.character(df[as.integer(taskid),4])`